# Parsing JSON in python instagram

Tags: python, json

Here is the response I get from instagram:

```
{"data": {"id": "###########", "bio": "Some text", "full_name": "Full Name", "profile_picture": "https://something.jpg", "website": "", "username": "username", "counts": {"followed_by": 139, "media": 38, "follows": 374}}, "meta": {"code": 200}}
```

I want to get the followed_by number so I thought I would use:

```
var["data"]["counts"]["followed_by"]
```

However this gives me this error:

```
indices must be integers
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I be using

```
for key, values in var.interitems:
```

Comment: Is the response perhaps a list of objects like what you provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the JSON first. Here is a working example using your data:

```
import json
response_text = """{"data": {"id": "###########", "bio": "Some text", "full_name": "Full Name", "profile_picture": "https://something.jpg", "website": "", "username": "username", "counts": {"followed_by": 139, "media": 38, "follows": 374}}, "meta": {"code": 200}}"""
response_dict = json.loads(response_text)
print response_dict["data"]["counts"]["followed_by"]
```